# XCTest pass in isolation, fail when run with other tests

Tags: ios, iphone, unit-testing, xctest

When I run a single XCTest class, all tests within succeed.

However when I run it together with other XCTest, some tests in the class fail.

setUp and tearDown method are implemented correctly as following:

```
- (void)setUp {
  [super setUp];
  ...
}

- (void)tearDown {
  ...
  [super tearDown];
}
```

I set a breakpoint in the code that should be executed in the test. When I was running the tests in isolation, the breakpoint was reached; when I was running it with other tests, the breakpoint was not reached. I'm thinking that maybe XCTest has some caching behaviors? If so, how to turn it off?

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I have only seen this happen when there is some global state or data saved to file that affects tests in different XCTest classes. Sorry that I cannot be of more help.

Comment: @LevLandau I set a breakpoint in the code that should be executed in the test. When I was running the tests in isolation, the breakpoint was reached; when I was running it with other tests, the breakpoint was not reached. I'm thinking maybe XCTest has some caching behaviors? If so, how to turn it off?

Comment: You need to post the test code itself, so that we can see what XCTest constructs you're using.

Comment: There's no caching here, something else is likely altering values causing your tests to fail. Unless you post more code it's impossible to know what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing the same behavior, and my issue was because I had a static variable in my method I was testing that was holding onto its value across tests.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue when I run all tests together. I could able to fix it by putting Assertion in Dispatch Delay,

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
       XCTAssert(self.response != nil)
    }
```

I hope the above solution works for you as well.